# Problem with running php script using mysql on tomcat

Tags: php

I am using tomcat 6 with JavaBridge. I have stored my php script in the following location.

```
C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\webapps\JavaBridge\project\test.php
```

In test.php I am using curl and mysql. The php.ini in JavaBridge is stored in the following location

```
C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\webapps\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\cgi\php.ini
```

and its contents are -

```
extension_dir="C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\webapps\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\cgi\x86-windows\ext"
include_path="C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\webapps\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\pear;."
```

there is also a config file called mysql.ini whose contents are -

```
extension = php_mysql.dll
```

I had also installed wamp earlier so I copied all the dll's from C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext to C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\webapps\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\cgi\x86-windows\ext

When I start tomcat and run my script I get the following error -

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\webapps\JavaBridge\project\test.php on line 534
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not enabled you have to enable curl in `php.ini` by uncommenting:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Comment: @unicornaddict: I solved the problem completely. See my answer.

Comment: @Jack: Good to know that..my current answer was for the curl issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support! I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem...actually my wamp has php 5.3.0 and the JavaBridge php.info() says its is 5.3.1. I copied the new dll's and it is working now. Now I get an error: undefined function curl_init(). For the benefit for someone who is also facing the same problem. I copied the following dll's -

```
libeay32.dll
ssleay32.dll
```

into C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\webapps\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\cgi and wrote the following line into mysql.ini

```
extension = php_curl.dll
```

and copied php_curl.dll into  C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\webapps\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\cgi\x86-windows\ext